# not able to click on element from drop down list?

Tags: javascript, protractor

HTML code :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#/profile">
      <i class="fa fa-user"></i> My Profile </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#/source">
      <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Source </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/user/logout">
      <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Logout </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My code :

```
element(by.cssContainingText('i.fa.fa-user', ' My Profile ')).click();
```

Problem : I am trying to click on element using class and cssContaingText but am not able to it. Please help me.

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have solved it via the `by.cssContainingText` also. The problem with your current approach is that you are checking the text inside the `i` element, which is in your case empty:

```
<a href="#/profile"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> My Profile </a>
```

The text to check is located inside the `a` element:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('ul.dropdown-menu > li > a', 'My Profile')).click();
```

---

Alternatively, you may solve it without checking the text:

```
element(by.css("a[href*=profile]")).click();
```

---

Though, I would agree that "by partial link text" option is a better choice in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer : I tried this code, it worked nicely.

```
element(by.partialLinkText('My Profile')).click();
```